# Centring a relative div to window in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center a div which has a relative position when the screen is less than `600px` it shifts to a dropdown (this is what I wanted to center).

I have tried doing `margin: 0 auto;`, but it doesn't seem to work.

The code can be found at http://www.bootply.com/S5hjublwBF

Help!

**Update:**

And it also underlaps with the text below of it when it drops down.

**Update 2:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="logo col-md-3 col-sm-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/120/people"></div>
            <div class="header-account col-md-4 col-sm-8">
                <div id="navIt" class="navYo">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Wishlist</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login/Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-cart col-md-4 col-sm-5">
                <p>Shopping Cart <a href="#">1 Item(s)</a> - $123 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* nav */
.navYo {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.navYo ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navYo li {
    margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navYo a {
    padding: 3px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    line-height: 100%;
}
.navYo a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.navYo .current a {
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* right nav */
.navYo.right ul {
    text-align: right;
}

/* center nav */
.navYo.center ul {
    text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .navYo {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 40px;
    }
    .navYo ul {

        width: 180px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border: solid 1px #aaa;
        /*content: "\f0c9";*/
        background: #fff no-repeat 10px 11px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }
    .navYo ul:before{
        content: "\f0c9";
        color: #0f0f0f;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        left:3px;
        position:absolute;
        top: 7px;
    }
    .navYo li {
        display: none; /* hide all <li> items */
        margin: 0;
    }
    .navYo .current {
        display: block; /* show only current <li> item */
    }
    .navYo a {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 32px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .navYo .current a {
        background: none;
        color: #666;
    }

    /* on nav hover */
    /*.nav ul:active {*/
        /*background-image: none;*/
    /*}*/
    /*.nav ul:active li {*/
        /*display: block;*/
        /*margin: 0 0 5px;*/
    /*}*/
    /*.nav ul:active .current {*/
        /*background: url(images/icon-check.png) no-repeat 10px 7px;*/
    /*}*/

    /* right nav */
    .navYo.right ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }

    /* center nav */
    .navYo.center ul {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -90px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /*on click hover */

    .drop ul {
        background-image: none;
    }

    .drop ul li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 5px;

    }

    .drop ul .current {
        background: url(images/icon-check.png) no-repeat 10px 7px;

    }
}

.header-account{
    text-align: center;
  }
 .header-cart{
      text-align: center;
    }
```

**Update 3**

It's for class `navYo`.

Comment: Always post your relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: And what div? Be specific with your question so that someone can help you.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Why do you add your js code in the question. It is irrelevant to your question. You should just post the code that is relevant to your question.

Comment: Your bootstrap classes should fill the 12-column layout. You have not managed that properly.

Comment: `navYo` div is already center.

Comment: @ketan the text has been centered but when the window goes less than `600px` then the problem comes

Comment: @BhojendraNepal yes but this is only an example

Comment: you mean to make image as center ??

Comment: @IqbalPasha No. `navYo` class when the screen size is less than 600px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ul is position absolute. To make it center in small size use following css to `.navYo ul`.

```
.navYo ul{
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right!!
just add

```
.navYo{
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As `ul` in navYo is at at absolute position it will not took full width of container.

Also `margin: 0 auto`; only work if you have width given to it.

Comment: This works but if the screen size goes less than `440` then it doesn't get centered.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the div with "#navIt" id then yes `margin: 0 auto` won't work. This is because the div has a width value of 0. The UL position in the div is absolute which means the parents width will not be calculated with the width of the UL included. Not sure why you made the UL position absolute but if you change it to relative you will notice that the parent will center using `margin: 0 auto`